# How to rearrange columns of a data frame based on values in a row

Tags: r

This is an R programming question. I would like to rearrange the order of columns in a data frame based on the values in one of the rows. Here is an example data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,3,4),B=c(3,2,4,1),C=c(2,1,4,3),
  D=c(4,2,3,1),E=c(4,3,2,1))
```

Suppose I want to rearrange the columns in df based on the values in row 4, ascending from 1 to 4, with ties having the same rank. So the desired data frame could be:

```
df <- data.frame(B=c(3,2,4,1),D=c(4,2,3,1),E=c(4,3,2,1),
  C=c(2,1,4,3),A=c(1,2,3,4))
```

although I am indifferent about the order of first three columns, all of which have the value 1 in column 4.

I could do this with a for loop, but I am looking for a simpler approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `select` - subset the row (4), `unlist`, `order` the values and pass it on `select`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    select(order(unlist(.[4, ])))
```

-output

```
  B D E C A
1 3 4 4 2 1
2 2 2 3 1 2
3 4 3 2 4 3
4 1 1 1 3 4
```

---

Or may use

```
df %>% 
     select({.} %>%
              slice_tail(n = 1) %>%
              flatten_dbl %>% 
              order)
  B D E C A
1 3 4 4 2 1
2 2 2 3 1 2
3 4 3 2 4 3
4 1 1 1 3 4
```

---

or in `base R`

```
df[order(unlist(tail(df, 1))),]
```